# Solving multiple ceil functions

Tags: algorithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

**Hello,**
I am working on an computer program and I am required to find the **least** possible value of $x$ for

> $\lceil \dfrac a x \rceil +  \lceil \dfrac b x \rceil +   \lceil \dfrac c x \rceil + \lceil \dfrac d x \rceil = H $

where $x,a,b,c,d,H$ are all integers and the values of $a,b,c,d$ and $H$ are given.
I am supposed to find the **least possible integral value** for $x$ such that the value of $H$ that will be formed (after substituting the values) should be **lesser than or equal to** the value of $H$ in the question but **not greater than** $H$. 
What I mean by this is that we need to find a **minimum possible integral** value for $x$ such that after plugging in the values of $a, b...$ the value of $H$ that we get is **maximum possible** and **not greater than** the proposed value of $H$ (See the examples for further understanding).

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/308618/solving-equations-involving-the-floor-function/308630#308630) question on *FLOOR* function but it was about multiplication and following the method they used to solve it, I got,

> $\lceil \dfrac a {n - \alpha} \rceil +  \lceil \dfrac b {n - \alpha} \rceil +   \lceil \dfrac c {n - \alpha} \rceil + \lceil \dfrac d {n - \alpha} \rceil = H $

where $n$ is the ceil of $x$ and $\alpha$ is the difference of $n$ and $x$. But this method has left me even more clueless on how to go about, since I'm pretty new to ceil and floor functions.
****** ***EXAMPLES*** ******
If the values are

> $A = 3, B = 5, C = 6, D = 8, H = 6$

then the equation formed will be

> $\lceil \dfrac 3 x \rceil +  \lceil \dfrac 5 x \rceil +   \lceil \dfrac 6 x \rceil + \lceil \dfrac 8 x \rceil = 6 $

for which the correct value for $x$ will be $5$ which is the lowest possible value since, if it is $6$ then the value of $H$ will be $5$ and if the value is $4$, then the value of $H$ will be $7$ which wont comply to the requirements of the value of $H$ and $x$.

But, If the values are

> $A = 3, B = 5, C = 6, D = 9, H = 7$

then the equation formed will be

> $\lceil \dfrac 3 x \rceil +  \lceil \dfrac 5 x \rceil +   \lceil \dfrac 6 x \rceil + \lceil \dfrac 9 x \rceil = 7 $

for which the **correct** integral value for $X$ will be $5$ since if $X = 4$ it would made $H = 8$ (Greater than the given value of $7$) and if $X = 6$ then it would make $H = 5$ (which would be smaller than the value for $x = 5$).

---

What I thought is that for questions like the second example once we get an fractional value for $x$ (after mathematically solving it) we can floor[ $\lfloor x \rfloor$ ] it.
***ANY HELP IS GREATLY APPRECIATED!!! (And  if it's not possible to reduce it to an easier equation, a algorithm to computer-solve it is also OK :P  )***

Comment: "the values of A,B,C,D and H are given such that H gets the greatest possible value" : would you care to elaborate? From your examples,  you do *not* mean given $A,B,C,D$ you set $H$ so that the problem has a solution and is as large as possible. Thus, what do you mean?

Comment: @username I'm sorry for my poor elaboration. I have elaborated it correctly now. Can you please check it out?

Answer (score 1):

So the question is $$ 
\text{maximize} \left(\left[\frac a x\right]+\left[\frac b x\right]+\left[\frac c x\right]+\left[\frac d x\right]\right)
$$  under the contraint that
$$
\left[\frac a x\right]+\left[\frac b x\right]+\left[\frac c x\right]+\left[\frac d x\right] \leq H
$$
The map
$$
x\to \left[\frac a x\right]+\left[\frac b x\right]+\left[\frac c x\right]+\left[\frac d x\right]
$$
is decreasing with $x$, and its smallest non trivial value is obtained for
$$
x_M=\max(a,b,c,d)
$$
where it is equal to the multiplicity of that maximum (1,2,3, or 4).

Indeed, if $x>a$, then $\frac a x <1$, so $\left[\frac a x\right]=0$, and similarly if $x>a$, $x>c$, $x>c$ and $x>d$, that is, $x>\max(a,b,c,d)=x_M$, then $\left[\frac a x\right] + \left[\frac b x\right] + \left[\frac c x \right]+\left[\frac d x\right] =0$, and depending if $a,b,c,d$ are equal or not, $\left[\frac a {x_M}\right] + \left[\frac b {x_M}\right] + \left[\frac c {x_M}\right]+\left[\frac d {x_M}\right]=1,2,3$ or $4$.

The largest value is obtained for $x_m=1$ where it is equal to $a+b+c+d$.

So to maximize under the constraint, and choose the best possible value between $x_m$ and $X_M$, a simple algorithm is a dichotomy.

Start with $(x_m,x_M)$.

Set $x= [(x_m+x_M)/2] $ and $ y= \left[\frac a x\right] + \left[\frac b x\right] + \left[\frac c x \right]+\left[\frac d x\right] $.

If $y>H$, set $x_m=x$ and start again.
If $y\leq H$, set $x_M=x$ and start again.

Stop when $x_M$ and $x_m$ are only 1 apart.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand from the part of xm = Max(a,b,c,d)

Comment: And can you please tell me what's the value of xM

Comment: @user538335 If $x>a$ then $\left[\frac{a}{x}\right]=0$, as $[y]=0$ if $y<1$...

Comment: Can you please modify your answer by including this explanation and giving some examples of the application of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-Let $f(x)=\lceil a/ x \rceil +  \lceil b/ x \rceil +   \lceil c/ x \rceil + \lceil d/ x \rceil$ with $a,b,c,d\gt0$ . We have 
$$f(x)\to \infty\text{ when } x\to 0\\f(x)\to 4\text{ when } x\to \infty$$ 
Can you explain to me better what you want to calculate? I do not understand well. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you should see that $f(1)=a+b+c+d=A$ and $f((0,1])=[A,\infty)$?

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor elaboration. I have elaborated it correctly now with more detailed examples. Can you please check it out?  Thank you