# Struggling to solve an equation containing a floor function

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to solve the following equation ($x\in \mathbb R)$
$$
2\lfloor{(x+1)^2+8}\rfloor=(x+1)(2x+3) \tag{1}
$$
I have tried substituting $x$ with its split form (integer part ($n$) + decimal part ($\alpha$)), i.e., $x=n+\alpha$ with $n=\lfloor x \rfloor.$

The substitution yields:
$$
\lfloor 2\alpha^2 + 4\alpha n + 4\alpha\rfloor=2\alpha^2+4\alpha n+5\alpha + 3n -15\tag{2}
$$
or equivalently
$$
\lfloor 2\alpha(\alpha + 2n +2)\rfloor= \alpha(2\alpha + 4n + 5) + 3n -15\tag{3}
$$

and here I am stuck and I don't know how to proceed, or whether I've already complicated matters more than needed.  Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott It is positive but why that affect the floor function? we can just remove them as you did?

Comment: @user929304: My apologies: I was interrupted by an emergency between seeing the question and writing that comment and badly misremembered the question when I returned. What I wrote was of course nonsense (which I have now deleted).

Comment: @Piquito: No, it was simply wrong (for reasons explained above in my comment to the OP, who had asked me to take a look at the question).

Answer (score 2):

> $$
> 2\lfloor{(x+1)^2+8}\rfloor=(x+1)(2x+3) \tag{1}
> $$

Let $~~(x+1) = P + r ~: ~P \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r < 1.$

Then, in (1) above,
the LHS equals 
$\displaystyle 2\lfloor (P + r)^2 + 8\rfloor = 
2P^2 + 16 + 2\lfloor 2Pr + r^2\rfloor$

and the RHS equals 
$\displaystyle (P+r)(2P+2r+1) = 2P^2 + 4Pr + 2r^2 + P + r.$

Therefore
$~~\displaystyle 
(P - 16) + (4Pr + 2r^2 + r) = 2\lfloor 2Pr + r^2\rfloor.$

Therefore
$$2(2Pr + r^2) - 2\lfloor 2Pr + r^2\rfloor
= (16 - P - r). \tag2$$

**Note**
For any Real Number $s$, you must have that 
$0 \leq \left(s - \lfloor s \rfloor \right) < 1.$ 
This implies that $0 \leq 2s - 2\lfloor s\rfloor < 2.$

Therefore, in (2) above, $0 \leq LHS < 2.$ 
Therefore, either $~P = 15, ~$ or $~P = 14$.

---

**Edit** 
$P = 16, r = 0$ also satisfies the constraints.

---

Further, in (2) above, 
$\displaystyle \lfloor 2Pr + r^2\rfloor = 
\lfloor r(2P + r)\rfloor \leq \lfloor 2P + r\rfloor = 2P.$ 
Therefore, $~~2\lfloor 2Pr + r^2\rfloor \leq 4P$.

Therefore, there must exist some $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,4P\}$ such that $k = 2\lfloor 2Pr + r^2\rfloor.$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1: }~P = 15}$
Examining (2) above, $~~P = 15 \implies ~\exists ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,60\}$ such that 
$\displaystyle 2(30r + r^2) - k = 1-r.$

This implies that 
$\displaystyle 2r^2 + 61r - (k+1) = 0 \implies $ 
$\displaystyle 
r = \frac{1}{4} \left[-61 \pm \sqrt{61^2 + 8k + 8}\right].$

Since $r \geq 0$, this implies that 
$\displaystyle 
r = \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{61^2 + 8k + 8} - 61\right]
= \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{3729 + 8k} - 61\right] ~: ~k \in \{0,1,\cdots, 60\}.$ 
Here, since $(x + 1) = P + r = 15 + r$,
you have that $x = 14 + r.$

The Case 1 **candidate** solutions are

- $x = 14 + r$.
- $r = \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{3729 + 8k} - 61\right]$.
- $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,60\}$.

On the RHS of (1) above, you have 
$(15 + r) (31 + 2r) = 465 + 61r + 2r^2 = 465 + (k + 1) = 466 + k.$

Therefore, values of $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 60\}$ must be inspected with respect to the LHS of equation (1) above, to see if they match the RHS of equation (1) above.

On the LHS of equation (1) above, 
$(15 + r)^2 + 8 = 233 + 30r + r^2 \implies $ 
the LHS of equation (1) equals 
$(2 \times 233) + 2\lfloor r^2 + 30r\rfloor.$

As $k$ ranges from $0$ through $60$, $r$ will be strictly between $0$ and $1$. 
From the analysis, $2r^2 + 61r = (k+1)$. 
Further, $~-1 < -r < 0 \implies k < 2r^2 + 60r < k+1.$

Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{k}{2} < r^2 + 30r < \frac{k + 1}{2}$.

Therefore $\displaystyle\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor = 
\lfloor r^2 + 30r\rfloor.$

Therefore, if $k$ even, you have that $2\lfloor r^2 + 30r\rfloor = 2 \times \lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor = 2 \times \frac{k}{2} = k.$

However, if $k$ odd, you have that $2\lfloor r^2 + 30r\rfloor = 2 \times \lfloor\frac{k}{2}\rfloor = 2 \times \frac{k-1}{2} = k-1.$

Therefore, in Case 1, the LHS of equation (1) above will match the RHS of equation (1) above only if $k$ is even.

Therefore, the Case 1 solutions are

- $x = 14 + r$
- $r = \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{3729 + 8k} - 61\right]$
- $k \in \{0,2,4,6,\cdots,60\}$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2: }~P = 14}$
Examining (2) above, $~~P = 14 \implies ~\exists ~k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,56\}$ such that 
$\displaystyle 2(28r + r^2) - k = 2-r.$

This implies that 
$\displaystyle 2r^2 + 57r - (k+2) = 0 \implies $ 
$\displaystyle 
r = \frac{1}{4} \left[-57 \pm \sqrt{57^2 + 8k + 16}\right].$

Since $r \geq 0$, this implies that 
$\displaystyle 
r = \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{57^2 + 8k + 16} - 57\right]
= \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{3265 + 8k} - 57\right] ~: ~k \in \{0,1,\cdots, 56\}.$ 
Here, since $(x + 1) = P + r = 14 + r$,
you have that $x = 13 + r.$

The Case 2 **candidate** solutions are

- $x = 13 + r$.
- $r = \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{3265 + 8k} - 57\right]$.
- $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,56\}$.

On the RHS of (1) above, you have 
$(14 + r) (29 + 2r) = 406 + 57r + 2r^2 = 406 + (k + 2) = 408 + k.$

Therefore, values of $k \in \{0,1,2,\cdots, 56\}$ must be inspected with respect to the LHS of equation (1) above, to see if they match the RHS of equation (1) above.

On the LHS of equation (1) above, 
$(14 + r)^2 + 8 = 204 + 28r + r^2 \implies $ 
the LHS of equation (1) equals 
$(2 \times 204) + 2\lfloor r^2 + 28r\rfloor.$

As $k$ ranges from $0$ through $56$, $r$ will be strictly between $0$ and $1$. 
From the analysis, $2r^2 + 57r = (k+2)$. 
Further, $~-1 < -r < 0 \implies k+1 < 2r^2 + 56r < k+2.$

Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{k+1}{2} < r^2 + 28r < \frac{k + 2}{2}$.

Therefore $\displaystyle\left\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2} \right\rfloor = 
\lfloor r^2 + 28r\rfloor.$

Therefore, if $k$ even, you have that $2\lfloor r^2 + 28r\rfloor = 2 \times \lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor = 2 \times \frac{k}{2} = k.$

However, if $k$ odd, you have that $2\lfloor r^2 + 28r\rfloor = 2 \times \lfloor\frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor = 2 \times \frac{k+1}{2} = k+1.$

Therefore, in Case 2, the LHS of equation (1) above will match the RHS of equation (1) above only if $k$ is even.

Therefore, the Case 2 solutions are

- $x = 13 + r$
- $r = \frac{1}{4} \left[\sqrt{3265 + 8k} - 57\right]$
- $k \in \{0,2,4,\cdots,56\}.$

Comment: Very well. The only integer solution that I have been able to find is $x=15$. It is complicated at first sight really.

Comment: @Piquito Your finding agrees with WolframAlpha which also gives 15 as the only solution.

Comment: @user929304 Use pencil,paper, and calculator.  For example, set $~k = 0~$ [or any element in $\{0,2,4,\cdots,60\}$], $~\displaystyle r = \frac{1}{4}\left[-61 + \sqrt{3729 + 8k}\right], ~x = 14 + r.$  Then manually verify that $x$ satisfies the original equation.  My only explanation is that Wolfram Alpha has rounding error trying to evaluate $\displaystyle \left\lfloor (x+1)^2 + 8\right\rfloor,~$ since $(x+1)^2$ is irrational.

Comment: @Piquito See my last comment.

Comment: @user929304 What do you think about my solution?

Comment: @user929304: I was not able to prove $15$ is unique.as integer solution.

Comment: @Piquito Doesn't my answer do that very simply?

Comment: @DerekLuna Personally, I agree that your answer does prove that 15 is the unique integer solution.

Comment: @Derek Luna: The problem asked about all the solutions, not just the integer ones.

Comment: @Piquito I know, but I was responding to this comment of  yours:" I was not able to prove $15$ is unique.as integer solution-Piquito".

Comment: @Derek Luna: Dear friend A comment usually is answered with a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of solutions (at most $60$), so we will describe a general way of finding them all as well as give an example of the method described.

---

Define the function

$$f(x)=2\lfloor{(x+1)^2+8}\rfloor-(x+1)(2x+3)$$

Note that

$$f(x)\leq 2(x+1)^2+16-(x+1)(2x+3)=15-x$$

$$f(x)\geq 2(x+1)^2+14-(x+1)(2x+3)=13-x$$

So if we have $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$ then it must be the case that

$$15-x_0\geq 0\Rightarrow15\geq x_0$$

$$13-x_0\leq 0 \Rightarrow 13\leq x_0$$

Thus $x_0\in [13,15]$. It is easily seen that $f(13)=2$ and $f(15)=0$. Let $x=13+r$ for some $r\in(0,2)$. Then

$$f(13+r)=2\lfloor r(r+28)\rfloor -2r^2-57r+2$$

Now, note that

$$0(0+28)=0$$

$$2(2+28)=60$$

Thus, the portion inside the floor function will travel through the integers $[1,2,...,59]$. Define

$$r_k=\sqrt{k+196}-14$$

and note that $r_k(r_k+28)=k$. Now, consider the intervals given by

$$S_0=(0,r_1)$$

$$S_1=[r_1,r_2)$$

$$S_2=[r_2,r_3)$$

$$\vdots$$

$$S_{59}=[r_{59},2)$$

For $r\in S_k$ we have

$$k=r_k(r_k+28)\leq r(r+28)<r_{k+1}(r_{k+1}+28)=k+1$$

and therefore

$$\lfloor r(r+28)\rfloor=k$$

(with a similar behavior at $S_0$ and $S_{59}$). Then for these $r\in S_k$ we know

$$f(13+r)=2k-2r^2-57r+2$$

This is a quadratic in $r$ which we can then solve to get

$$r_0=\frac{\sqrt{16k+3265}-57}{4}$$

We just need to check each $k\in [0,1,...,59]$ and see if the $r_0$ defined above falls in the interval $S_k$. If it does, then we have a root. If not, then we do not have a root. For example, for $k=5$ we have

$$r_0=\frac{\sqrt{3345}-57}{4}=0.21$$

and

$$S_5=[r_5,r_6)=[\sqrt{207}-14,\sqrt{208}-14)=[0.38,.42)$$

Thus, there is no root corresponding to $k=5$. However, if we instead chose $k= 8$ then

$$r_0=\frac{3\sqrt{377}-57}{4}=0.3123$$

$$S_8=[0.2829,0.3178)$$

Since $r_0\in S_8$, we conclude $f(13+r_0)=0$ (this can [be checked](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fullsimplify%5B2floor%28%28%2813%2B1%2F4%20%28-57%20%2B%203%20sqrt%28377%29%29%29%2B1%29%5E2%2B8%29-%28%2813%2B1%2F4%20%28-57%20%2B%203%20sqrt%28377%29%29%29%2B1%29%282%2813%2B1%2F4%20%28-57%20%2B%203%20sqrt%28377%29%29%29%2B3%29%5D) if one wishes). Just do this for all $k\in [0,1,...,59]$ and you will have all the solutions.

Comment: It would be better if you write in your first example of numeric calculation $r_0\approx0.21$ instead of $r_0=0.21$ because you do have $r_0\approx0.20899374092$ and mainly because in this  problem very small differences are important indeed.

Comment: Fair point, but the method stands anyways. That's why I included more decimals for the $k=8$ case as they actually impact the result in the end.

Comment: Per my answer there are $1 + 31 + 29 = 61$ solutions, given that $~\lfloor ~x ~\rfloor~$ may equal $15, 14,~$ or $~13$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be an integer.
Set $y = x+1$, then we have $2\lfloor y^{2}+8 \rfloor=y(2y+1)=2y^{2}+y. $

Since $\lfloor a+c \rfloor = \lfloor a \rfloor +c$ for all integers $a$, $2\lfloor y^{2}+8 \rfloor=2(\lfloor y^{2} \rfloor + 8)=2\lfloor y^{2} \rfloor +16=2y^{2}+y$ from above.

If $y > 16$, then $2\lfloor y^{2} \rfloor = 2y^{2} + c$ for some $c > 0 \implies 2y^{2}<2 \lfloor y^{2} \rfloor \implies y^{2}<\lfloor y^2 \rfloor$ which is a contradiction as $\lfloor a \rfloor \leq a$ for all $a$ by definition.

Hence, we must check the finite number of cases of the form $y \leq 16 \implies x \leq 15$.

Since $x$ is an integer ($\implies y$ is an integer), then $2y^{2}+16=2\lfloor y^{2} \rfloor +16=2y^{2}+y \implies$

$y = 16 \implies x = 15.$

Therefore $15$ is the only integer solution.

Comment: I thought that your analysis was valid, as far as it went.  However, per my answer, there is no reason not to explicitly compute each solution.  The key is to obtain an expression that looks like $2(s) - 2\lfloor s\rfloor = \text{something}.$  Everything in my answer depended on that specific trick.  Also, generally, in problems like this, you want to identify the integer part of the variable, and the fractional part.  For example, I used $(x + 1) = P + r, ~P \in \Bbb{Z}, ~0 \leq r < 1.$

Comment: Note also, that for each pertinent value of $P < 16$ to explore (i.e $P = 15$ or $P = 14$), I established a range for $k$, and then verified that throughout that range, you would always have $0 \leq r < 1.$  This allowed me to conclude that each appropriate (i.e. even numbered) value of $k$ generated a valid solution.  This allowed me to conclude, fairly painlessly, that there were $(1 + 31 + 29 = 61)$ valid solutions.

Comment: Also, consider how I used that when (for example) $P = 15$, I had that $2r^2 + 61r = (k+1).$  This made it much easier to evaluate the LHS of the original problem, which included $\displaystyle 2\left\lfloor r^2 + 30r \right\rfloor.
$

Comment: Dear friend: In your equality $\lfloor a+c \rfloor = \lfloor a \rfloor +c\space\space$, $LHS$ is an integer but $RHS$ does not.

Comment: @Piquito, ah but then the analysis for integers still works because $x \in \mathbb{Z} \implies y \in \mathbb{Z} \implies y^{2} \in \mathbb{Z}$ and since $c = 8$ the equality works. So this just means there are possibly non-integer solutions outside of $y \leq 16$.